# Use the "forEach" method to add properties to "friendsObj"? Use index as key and name as the value of property.friendsObj will have with 3 properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Here is my current code

```
 var friendsObj = {};

var friends = ['John', 'Peter', 'Mary'];

 friends.forEach(function(name, index) {
  // implement your code below
    console.log('Index '+ index + ' equals ' + name ) ;
  });

console.log(friendsObj[0] === 'John');
// -> true
console.log(friendsObj[1] === 'Peter');
// -> true
console.log(friendsObj[2] === 'Mary');
// -> true
```

The results are this

Index 0 equals John
Index 1 equals Peter
Index 2 equals Mary
false
false
false
Randomized with seed 51872
Started
F

Says that friendsObj should have "John", "Peter", and "Mary" as properties. I don't understand how it is not connecting back to friendsObj? Open to suggestions, thank you so much!

Comment: "*I don't understand how it is not connecting back to friendsObj?*" because there is no code that ever changes `friendsObj`. Computers only do what you tell them, not what you want.

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the property in the object for each index to be the element value.

```js
var friendsObj = {};
var friends = ['John', 'Peter', 'Mary'];
friends.forEach(function(name, index) {
  friendsObj[index] = name;
});
console.log(friendsObj);
console.log(friendsObj[0] === 'John');
console.log(friendsObj[1] === 'Peter');
console.log(friendsObj[2] === 'Mary');
```

This can be written more concisely by directly converting the array into a regular object with spread syntax.

```js
let friends = ['John', 'Peter', 'Mary'];
let friendsObj = {...friends};
console.log(friendsObj);
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I was making it more difficult. Greatly appreciated